# nanoTime and currentTimeMillis have different rates on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to measure the duration of some period with both `System.nanoTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()`. And the longer the period gets, the greater difference I obtain from two measurements.

Here is a small snippet demonstrating the problem:

```
public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
        long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (true) {
            long nowNanos = System.nanoTime();
            long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println((nowMillis - startMillis) - (nowNanos - startNanos) / 1000000);

            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

When running on Mac OS with jdk 1.8.0_74 there is a clear trend that values decrease by around 2ms per minute. I.e. at first I see only 0 and 1, but after 10 minutes there are values around -20.

I managed to observe such behaviour only on mac with jdk8, couldn't reproduce it on linux and on windows with both jdk 7 and 8.

So, the question is: who is lying? I know that `nanoTime()` should be preferred to measure duration. But in this case I'm not sure it is true.

Can someone elaborate on this topic?

Comment: I see a similar thing happening on Windows 7 x64 with Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NTP, most likely your currentTimeMillis is being corrected, so it is the one most likely to be right.  The nanoTime() is based on the clock cycles/clock frequency. If this frequency is slightly off which it *measures* you will see a constant drift. This shouldn't be based on the version of Java but rather the OS and hardware.

Comment: Running on the same hardware with java 7 doesn't produce this drift. I think I even found the explanation in jdk sources.
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/f96d42d605e1/src/os/bsd/vm/os_bsd.cpp
os::javaTimeNanos is defined twice in lines 1022 and 1048. If 1022 is used then the drift appears.

Comment: Bug report for the HotSpot? :)

Answer (score 0):

Both are lying :)

Time cannot be measured with absolute precision. Every timer in you computer will always have a slight drift. Since currentTimeMillis and nanoTime may come from different timers its completely natural that you observe a drift between the two. The drift may even *vary* depending on your computers operating state (e.g. work load on the machine may change its temperature and in turn cause a slight variation of the clock generator. These effects are small, but theyre always there).

In cases where there appears to be no drift both currentTimeMillis and nanoTime are either driven by the same hardware timer, or there is a correction meachanism at work either in the OS or the VM.

Comment: I understand that we cannot measure time with absolute precision. But 2 ms every minute make up almost 3 seconds per day which seems too much. Moreover, I have evidence that there _is_ a way to eliminate the drift, because it isn't present in jdk7.

I wonder if this change in jdk was intentional and whether it is a known issue, because it is 100% reproducible on other machines as well.

Comment: There is a very simple way to eliminate drift: use the same timer source for both. The drawback is that either nanoTime's granularity is then coarse or currentTimeMillis is based on a high frequency source with a generally higher drift. My point is: absolute drift is a *normal* phenomenon and relative drift is a natural consequence of independend timers. It may well be that there were changes between JRE's to *improve* either granularity or *reduce* drift that cause the difference to be exposed. Not seeing *relative* drift in JRE7 does not mean it was a *better* implementation.